# Only load and play visible GIFs, pause no-longer-visible ones: is it possible?

Tags: gif

I want to create an online GIF library. I don't have any code yet because I'm only asking if what I want to do **is actually possible to achieve**:

- Only **load and play** the GIFs that are in the browser's view;
- **Pause** GIFs that are no longer in the browser's view (after scrolling down)

Is this doable?

Please check this figure: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq4GD.png)

Comment: Reacting to when stuff is/ comes inside the viewport is something many “lazy load” plugins do, so do some more research in that direction. Intersection Observer API is the keyword to do this in a “modern” way. But you can not really “pause” a GIF in the first place. Removing them from the DOM, or replacing them with a video would be the options in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load only GIFs in viewpoint and load new as you scroll. 
It is possible to hide GIFs that are no longer in viewpoint. 
You can't really pause images of GIF format. You would have to use some video format like WEBM or MP4, for pausing. For example, Facebook is using video to achieve "pausing gif" effect.